# MongoDB: multiple indexex

Tags: database, mongodb, database-indexes

Is it possible to create more than one text index and more than one array index in one collection in MongoDB?

I don't mean the single index with multiple fields.

Comment: As far as I remember you can't have multiple text index in a single collection. MongoDB allows you to create multiple, however, gives error while searching. Refer: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8127

Comment: @fiveelements Thanks, you helped a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Text Indexes :** MongoDB doesn't allow user to create multiple single field text indexes, it makes sense as in your query you won't specify field name when using `$text` search($text search is meant for text indexes), if you really need it, you can create a compound text index and use weights as an option - that way you're saying your query's are most likely matched to a particular field in a compound text index.

Ref : [Text Indexes MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html) , [$text search Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html)

**Multi-Key Indexes :**

1. You can create & would create multi-key indexes same as like creating
   other indexes types(I mean to say you no need to pass any options
   like when creating unique/sparse etc.).
2. *At the time of creation of index* - MongoDB would automatically
   converts a normal index to multi-key index if it finds an array in any of the document for a
   particular field being indexed or *After index is created* then at any time - mongoDB can convert an index to multi-key index if
   an array is inserted in any document on a particular field.
3. You can check **Multi-Key Indexes** by finding
   `isMultiKey : true` on a index upon doing `getIndexes()` on a collection.

**Limitations of Multi-Key Indexes** :

1. Remember **not to create a compound index in which both fields are arrays**, cause it would explode as it needs to create index keys on Cartesian product of those two fields.
2. Additionally, mongoDB would throw an error if you try to insert a
   document with two fields as arrays, where the two fields are already compound indexed.

---

Ref : [MultiKey Indexes MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations)

Answer (score 1):

Adding my comment as an answer fo easy future reference.

As far as I remember you can't have multiple text `index` in a single `collection`. MongoDB allows you to create multiple text `index`, however, gives error while searching. Refer: jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8127